# If block all incoming traffic and disable UPnP can I still browse the web?

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, upnp

Excuse my ignorance but it seems I that I don't know why *something* on the Internet needs to connect to you

Below is the firewall options in my BT Hub

[image]

To my understanding the firewall blocks ALL incoming traffic EXCEPT what's allowed by UPnP and manual port forwarding.

This explains why the torrent client on my PC works perfectly because it uses UPnP to open the required ports

[image]

IF I disable the UPnP I assume the torrent client will NOT work properly anymore, I don't have any manual port forwarding

[image]

What about the browser? will stop working because it uses UPnP as well?
or it will not stop working because it the websites I browse do NOT need to connect back to me? unlike the peers in my torrent client who (for some reason) need to connect back to me?

Comment: The browser will still work. Note it says "Block all **unsolicited** incoming traffic" When you ask for a web page that means the returned page is **solicited** and the traffic will be allowed.

Comment: A torrent works by announcing yourself to a swarm and other peers in that swarm will see what you're requesting and offer it to you. In order to give you what you're looking for they need to connect to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peer-to-Peer protocols **require that at least one side can accept incoming connections**. So if half of the users on your favorite torrent tracker have UPnP enabled, you can disable UPnP and still connect to half of the peers. If you enable UPnP, you will be able to connect to all the peers which are online. This doesn't make a big difference for popular torrents, but if something is only shared by a couple of peers who don't have UPnP, you won't be able to get those files at all unless you enable UPnP on your side.

The same is true for some games (usually you'll need UPnP if you want to host a multi-player game), and was true for Skype a long time ago. Novadays, both Skype and the majority of popular games are backed by online servers which retire the need for incoming connections.

Computer systems with UPnP enabled are an attractive target for hackers: if you get infected by a virus, not only can it steal your personal data, but also sit in the background accepting connections from its author. That's how most [botnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) work. So, unless you can see a direct benefit from UPnP (programs which wouldn't work otherwise, downloads which slow down significantly with UPnP disabled), you should disable it. Go to that UPnP Settings page on your first screenshot, disable UPnP, check if your favorite programs still work and only re-enable UPnP if they don't

Answer (score 2):

If you disable UPnP on your router, uTorrent will still work, it will just have a bit more hard time establishing connections with seeds and peers, hence your downloads might become a bit slower. uTorrent won't receive any **new** incoming connections initiated by devices on the internet, but, it will still be able to initiate outgoing connections.

Disabling/enabling UPnP won't affect your web browsing experience at all. To help you understand that, I'll try to explain to you briefly how firewall works.

If you leave your firewall setting to "default", it will allow any device on your internal network to initiate new connections to anywhere on the internet. Your firewall "remembers" these connections for a period of time. Once it receives some traffic from the internet, it checks if it belongs to an "established" or "related" connection. If it does, it allows the traffic to pass through. But, when your firewall detects **new** incoming traffic, initiated somewhere on the internet, it will block it, unless you specifically allow it to pass through by "opening a port" for example.

That's why browsing and many other things won't be affected by disabling UPnP - your computer will initiate the connection, and when your router receives some data back, it will know it belongs to an established connection by your computer and it'll forward the data to it.

Now "opening ports", for programs that need to accept new incoming connections from the internet, can be annoying and time consuming, and here's where UPnP comes in: an application on your computer can, with help of UPnP, now just tell your router: "Hey, open this port and forward traffic that comes through it to this computer."

While UPnP could be a small security risk, and you could probably live just fine without it, I wouldn't recommend you to change the firewall setting from default. The way it works - it's good.

Comment: How do I know if I certain program needs port forwarding or not? the browser does not obviously but what about Skype? or even playing Xbox?

Comment: Well, the most certain way is to just run the program and see if it works ok. Last time I checked, Skype will work, but you might sometimes have issues with file transfer. I'm not sure about Xbox as I don't have it, but I'd recommend that you first check if it works as it should. If not, google for "whatever_doesn't_work open ports." Both Xbox and Skype can use UPnP to open/forward required ports.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Everything should work with default (allow outgoing and deny incoming).

Basically, you only need to open ports if you use various servers that have to accept connections that are being initialized from the outside (like hosting a ftp server for example).

Since most applications connect from you to external servers, fort forwarding is becoming quite rarely used for home users.

Answer (score 1):

Consumer routers (including BT Hub) make it very hard to passively (changing settings beside disabling the WAN connection) block the ability to access the internet in a web browser.

The settings you are referring to are for INBOUND connections meaning some host on the internet tries contacting your networks router via your public IP address.

It's like if you setup your phone to block any incoming calls; excluding well known contacts.

In regards to how a P2P based application like BitTorrent it will still work, however it will be heavily impacted in transferring data. While it should *still work* but in a very limited capacity as no outside connections (connections being initiated by a remote host) can be established, which means any connections MUST be initiated by your system which is not ideal since it leads to more work for the application to find a host that will accept requests and transfers.